# how can I add Action to a texture packer in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to create eventListner on each image (playIcon,pauseIcon) but its not working using  touchUp and touchDown

here is my code:

```
TextureAtlas buttonsPlayPause = new TextureAtlas("uiii/uiii.pack");
skin.addRegions(buttonsPlayPause);
TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
textButtonStyle.font = font;
textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("pauseIcon");
textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("playIcon");
TextButton button = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
button.setY(pauseY);
button.setX(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6);
button.setSize(150,150);
stage.addActor(button);

//pause/playAction
button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {resume();
              }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
         pause();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

What happens now is that the button listener behaves as 'istouched()' rather than 'justtouched()'.  When I click the button, the game is paused but whenever I remove my finger, there's no pause, the game runs.

Comment: Have you set stage as InputProcessor by this Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

Comment: It's still unclear from your comment what you want to happen, and what's wrong with how it currently behaves.

Comment: @Tenfour04. What happens now is that the button listener behaves as 'istouched()' rather than 'justtouched()'.  When I click the button, the game is paused but whenever I remove my finger, there's no pause, the game runs

Comment: @AbhishekAryan please read my edit

Comment: That's expected because you call `resume()` in your `touchUp` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want this button to toggle between Play and Pause, calling either `pause()` or `resume()` based on current state.

The Button class already has a built-in internal InputListener, so all you need is a ChangeListener to react to button presses:

```
//pause/playAction
button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        if (button.isChecked())
            resume();
        else
            play();
    }
});
```

Make sure you mark it `final` when you first declare it, so the listener can reference it:

```
//...
final TextButton button = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
//...
```