# Libgdx: pause without triggering justtouch

Tags: java, libgdx

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081110/how-can-i-add-action-to-a-texture-packer-in-libgdx), it works perfectly, the only problem I'm having is that the whole game is based on touch events, when a user touches the screen, an object gets created.

What's happening now is that when a user touches the pause button (texture packer), an object gets created and the game is paused. I want to prevent objects from being created if the pause is touched. I used to be able to do something like this:

```
private Vector3 touchPos; 
touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0); 
camera.unproject(touchPos); 

if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
 if (touchPos.x > pauseX && touchPos.x < pauseX + pauseX) {
  if (touchPos.y > pauseY && touchPos.y < pauseX + pauseY) {
   setGamePause(!getGamePause());
  }}}
```

But doesn't seem to be working with texture packer, maybe my implementation is wrong, not sure, is there another approach?

```
private float pauseY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 115;
private float pauseX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 6;
button.setSize(150, 150)
```

It's on the top left of the screen

Comment: Not sure what a texture packer has to do with this?

Comment: @1blustone so it's me implementing the method above in a wrong way? or is there another way of doing it

Comment: I mean I'm not quite sure what you mean with the title - so all you want to do is stop/resume everything (including object creation) when you press the button? Take a look at [Ashley](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley) and create Systems for everything, and just stop calling `engine.update` when the game is true. Of course, keep your pause button outside of the `Engine` so you can resume it :)

Comment: @1blustone yes I dont want to trigger just touch or as you said

Answer (score 1):

If `pauseX` and `pauseY` is left position and right position of a rectangle/button respectively then

you need width and height of button/rectangular area, like suppose that `buttonWidth`, `buttonHeight`.

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
   if (touchPos.x > pauseX && touchPos.x < pauseX + button.getWidth()) {
      if (touchPos.y > pauseY && touchPos.y < pauseY + button.getHeight()) {
          setGamePause(!getGamePause());
      }
   }
}
```

Please Check Test :

```
public class GdxTest extends Game  implements  InputProcessor{

    private Stage stage;
    Vector3 vector3;
    TextButton button;
    float pauseX,pauseY;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        vector3=new Vector3();
        ExtendViewport extendViewport=new ExtendViewport(700,1200,new OrthographicCamera());
        stage=new Stage(extendViewport);

        Skin skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));
        skin.get("font-label", BitmapFont.class).getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

        pauseX=300;
        pauseY=500;
        button=new TextButton("Pause",skin);
        button.setPosition(pauseX,pauseY);

        stage.addActor(button);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.draw();
        stage.act();

        ////Touch Detection without processor

        vector3.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);
        stage.getCamera().unproject(vector3);

        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
             if(vector3.x>pauseX && vector3.x<pauseX+button.getWidth()  && vector3.y>pauseY && vector3.y<pauseY+button.getHeight())
                 System.out.println("TOuched");
         }

         ///////
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width,height);
        stage.getViewport().update(width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
       stage.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button1) {

        vector3.set(screenX,screenY,0);
        stage.getCamera().unproject(vector3);

        if(vector3.x>pauseX && vector3.x<pauseX+button.getWidth() && vector3.y>pauseY && vector3.y<pauseY+button.getHeight())
            System.out.println("TOuched");


        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work, please check my updated question, perhaps it's my fault

Comment: I've added a Test class in my Answer.

Comment: will test it tonight and let u know, i tested the first partt didn't work, left and forgot to test `public boolean touchDown`

Comment: First part of TestClass ?